# ¿Puedo poner un lenguaje predeterminado en Sublime text?

Tags: python, sublimetext

estoy arrancando en la programación y estoy probando el editor de código Sublime Text. Cada vez que tengo que iniciar otro archivo, tengo que meterme en las configuraciones y volver a elegir Python.
Quería saber si existe alguna forma de empezar un nuevo programa y que este se inicie en lenguaje Python automáticamente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Y no guardas el archivo como .py y se aplica python automaticamente ??

Comment: eso depende de la extension del archivo, si es `.py` esto tendras que ejecutarlo con `python file.py` , si es `.js` puede ser un archivo web o uno de node, esto dependera del archivo